# how to remove event listener from fabricjs canvas

Tags: jquery, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs to build an interactive  map in html5.

When the DOM loads, I add my mouseover listener to my fabricjs canvas instance by calling: *my_event_setter( **true** )*.

Then for the sake of testing, I want to remove the listener once I do my first mouseover by calling: *my_event_setter( **false** )*. That should thus remove the mouseover listener, but it does not.

```
my_event_setter = function( toggle )
  { var lvo =  { 'object:over' : function(e){ mouseover_handler( e ) } } ;
    toggle ? my_fabric_canvas.on( lvo ) : my_fabric_canvas.off( lvo ) ;
  } 
mouseover_handler = function( e )
  { my_event_setter( false ) ;
  }
```

Comment: Good catch. `.off` currently doesn't support object notation (like `on` does) but probably should. Please [file a bug on github](http://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues)

Comment: in the meantime, what is the appropriate way to clear listeners ... ... ... ... ...  ... ... ... jQuery("#my_canvas_element").off( 'object:over' ... )?? .... .....  .. ... .. .. ... ... ... ... ... ... ... jQuery(my_fabric_canvas).off( 'object:over' ... )??

Comment: `my_fabric_canvas.off('object:over', eventHandler)` (make sure eventHandler is original reference)

Comment: kangax ... that seems to be working ... so, in terms of stackoverflow, that is the answer ... hint, hint :)

Comment: I submitted the issue to the github.

Comment: also, how to send arguments using non-object solution? ................................. my_fabric_canvas.off('object:over', eventHandler , { "can_I_send_args" : "???" } )

Comment: args to `off`? which args?

Comment: aha ... I should have been more clear ... is it possible to send arguments to the event handler? ... by default the handler receives the event object, per-se.

Comment: `canvas.on('object:over', function(options) {
  eventHandler(options, arg1, arg2);
});`

Comment: I tried that but that does not work ... it seems that the anonymous handler breaks the rule _"make sure eventHandler is original reference"_ ... ... ...

Comment: function f(opts){ eventHandler(opts, arg1, arg2) } canvas.on('object:over', f); canvas.off('object:over', f);

Comment: that's currently what I am doing ... which works of course, so it's ok. the only bad thing about that is that I have to have a unique 'relay'  function for every listener: object:over/out/down/up ... which is no real big deal. it's a trivial issue :)

Comment: Aaaand, fixed! https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/commit/1e1adc783102c16aa53e8ca1324d13c192c8a9a6

Answer (score 11):

This example shows how to remove the mousemove when mouseup is fired:

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', function () {
    canvas.off('mouse:move', eventHandler);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by using:

```
var canvas = fabric.Canvas.activeInstance;
canvas.__eventListeners["mouse:down"] = [];
```

The events are in an Array so it makes it easy to handle these.

Comment: To reset all canvas enents in fabric js, we need to use   canvas.__eventListeners = { };

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution to destroy all the events:

```
canvas.__eventListeners = {}
```

If you want to remove only some of the events iterate through the properties of the __eventListeners object:

```
for (var prop in canvas.__eventListeners) {
    if (canvas.__eventListeners.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop === 'mouse:up') {
        delete canvas.__eventListeners[prop]
    }
}
```

Or with new `Object.keys`:

```
Object.keys(canvas.__eventListeners).forEach((prop) => {
    if (prop === 'mouse:up' || prop === 'object:moving')) {
        delete canvas.__eventListeners[prop]
    }
})
```

Comment: canvas.__eventListeners is not defined.

Comment: @SteveOwens what versions of FabricJS are you using? The canvas element needs to be a Fabric class. var canvas = new fabrics.Canvas()

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeEvent(eventName: string) {
  let lisnr = canvas.__eventListeners[eventName][0];
  canvas.off(eventName, lisnr);
}
```

I'm doing this, considering there's only one event registered for "eventName". I had to do this because I had to bind few params to my listener before registering and which changes the listener instance.
In the case of anonymous function, we can go with the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

Bind event with angular js like

```
$scope.closeCurve = function(){
    canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
    canvas.on('mouse:up', function() {
      canvas.getObjects().forEach(o => {
        o.fill = 'blue'
      });
      canvas.renderAll();
    });
  };
```

Remove event like

```
$scope.selectTool = function(){
    canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
    canvas.off('mouse:up');
  };
```

bind with on method and remove from off method...:)