# send data to function using event handler (.on) in fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

As the title explain, i'm trying to send data to a function by event handler.

i've tried the following:

```
canvas.on("mouse:wheel",{name:"spin"}, constructSpin);
function constructSpin(e){
console.log(e.data.name);
}
```

sadly this is not working :(

is there any way to send data to a function using event handler ?

**NOTE**: i've found this in fabric document:

> on(eventName, handler) → {Self}

so it look like there is no **data** in on construction !

Comment: Are you allowed to bind ? you could try: `constructSpin.bind(null, {name:"spin"}); `. Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should construct and call the  **`constructSpin`** function in the following way, if you wish to pass some custom data on `mouse:wheel` event :

```
canvas.on("mouse:wheel", function(e) {
   constructSpin(e, { name: "spin" });
});

function constructSpin(event, data) {
   console.log(data.name);
}
```

Comment: thank u that helped !
but what if i want to stop that event with specific handler ?
there is no function handler so i think `canvas.off("mouse:wheel",??);` will not work ?
i have more than one wheel event in canvas and i don't want to delete them all :(
is there are solution to this ?

Comment: Yes you're right `canvas.off("mouse:wheel",??);` will not work. In your case [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27787297/7750640) solution might be suitable. Here is a demo - https://jsfiddle.net/thh84fa3/

Answer (score 0):

The fabric events are sort of syntetic.
You are spinning the wheel on the canvas element and you get back 2 events, one at canvas level and one at object level.

if `spin` is a particular object on your canvas, or is a name property of your objects you can have:

```
canvas.on("mouse:wheel", function(opt) {
  // opt.e => real event
  // opt.target => object where you spinned over
  // opt.target.name maybe is what are you looking for
});
```

If my assumption is wrong, you can just do what is already suggested in another answer:

```
canvas.on("mouse:wheel", function(opt) {
  // opt.e => real event
  // opt.target => object where you spinned over
  opt.name = 'spin'
  yourFunction(opt);
});
```